# Why do my EntityFramework 6.1 Indexes using a custom DbInitializer not work?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I got a tiny model:

```vb
Public Class Thing
  Public Property Id As Integer
  Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

A matching `DbContext`:

```vb
Public Class Context
  Inherits DbContext

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("EfCodeFirstUniqueConstraintTest")
  End Sub

  Public Property Things As IDbSet(Of Thing)

  Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
    BuildConstraints(modelBuilder)
  End Sub

  Private Sub BuildConstraints(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of Thing).Property(Function(m) m.Name) _
      .HasMaxLength(255) _
      .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, _
                           New IndexAnnotation(New IndexAttribute("UniqueOrgUnitName") _
                                               With {.IsUnique = True}))
  End Sub
End Class
```

When I put this into a Solution with EF6.1 using this code:

```vb
Sub Main()
  Using db As New Context
    Dim t = New Thing With {.Name = "Thingy"}
    db.Things.Add(t)
    db.SaveChanges()
  End Using
End Sub
```

everything works as expected. The 2. run will throw an exception for there is a unique index violation.

Unfortunately, I need my application to not throw away the whole DB. So I wrote a table and constraints dropping `DbInitializer` like this:

```vb
Public Class DbIniter
  Implements IDatabaseInitializer(Of Context)
  Public Sub InitializeDatabase(context As Context) Implements IDatabaseInitializer(Of Context).InitializeDatabase
    DropAllTables(context)
    Dim dbCreationScript = CType(context, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript()
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbCreationScript)
    CreateMetaDataTable(context)
    Seed(context)
    context.SaveChanges()
  End Sub
  Protected Sub DropAllTables(context As Context)
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'")
    Dim remainingTrys = 100
    Dim everythingOk = False
    While Not everythingOk AndAlso remainingTrys > 0
      Try
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_MSforeachtable ""DECLARE @name nvarchar(max); SET @name = parsename('?', 1); EXEC sp_MSdropconstraints @name""")
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'")
        everythingOk = True
      Catch ex As Exception
        remainingTrys = remainingTrys - 1
      End Try
    End While
    If Not everythingOk Then Throw New System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.RetryLimitExceededException(String.Format("Database was not empty after last attempt."))
  End Sub

  Protected Sub CreateMetaDataTable(context As Context)
    Dim sql = "CREATE TABLE dbo.__MigrationHistory ( MigrationId NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CreatedOn DATETIME NOT NULL, Model VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL, ProductVersion NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);" _
              & " ALTER TABLE dbo.__MigrationHistory ADD PRIMARY KEY (MigrationId); INSERT INTO dbo.__MigrationHistory (MigrationId, CreatedOn, Model, ProductVersion) VALUES ('InitialCreate', GetDate(), @p0, @p1);"

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, GetModel(context), GetProductVersion())
  End Sub

  Protected Function GetModel(context As Context) As Byte()
    Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream
      Using gzipStream As New GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress)
        Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(gzipStream, New XmlWriterSettings With {.Indent = True})
          EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(context, writer)
        End Using
      End Using
      Return memoryStream.ToArray
    End Using
  End Function

  Protected Overridable Sub Seed(context As Context)
  End Sub

  Protected Function GetProductVersion() As String
    Return GetType(DbContext).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(False).OfType(Of Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute).Single.InformationalVersion
  End Function
End Class
```

Using this initializer, my indexes will never hit the database. Everything else works just fine.

`ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript()` will not return any SQL for the indexes:

```sql
create table [dbo].[Things] (
    [Id] [int] not null identity,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
```

Using the default `DbInitializer`, the SQL sent to the DB looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Things] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Things] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

followed by another statement like this:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UniqueOrgUnitName] ON [dbo].[Things]([Name])
```

Does someone have any insight into why this does not work?

Where would the index-SQL come from when it is not included in what `CreateDatabaseScript()` does return?

Comment: The bundled EF `DbInitializer`s do call an internal `Database.Create()` overload using a parameter of type `DatabaseExistenceState`. When I call the public, parameterless `Create()`, I get an exception: "...cannot be created because it already exists".

Comment: Why do you need to handle MigrationHistory? Actually sometimes I have some problem with validation (simple to see so I could also have with indexes) and it seems that I can solve it if I use both fluent interface and data annotation to configure entities (I know, very strange). You could start trying adding data annotation on your entity.

Comment: I do create a MigrationHistory so that EntityFramework will notice that the schema is up to date.

Comment: Actually is quite hard to me to understand why you are solving your problem in this way. Why don't you just drop all tables then you make EF to create database objects for you? Anyway, your code does not call the right EF interface, below some more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the history of EF but writing an EF provider (https://jetentityframeworkprovider.codeplex.com/) I've seen that some old EF versions used to generate object items using `DbProviderServices` interface. That interface (the interface you are using with your initializer) works on `StoreItemCollection` that I'm quite sure that does not contain information about indexes but only about `EntitySet` (entities) and `AssociationSet` (relationships). In the project above the implementation is in `JetCreateSqlGenerator` class.

Since some EF version, the EF does not use `DbProviderServices` anymore to generate database objects, or, better, if the EF Provider provides a `MigrationSqlGenerator` the EF uses that interface otherwise the EF use the old `DbProviderServices`. `MigrationSqlGenerator` provides Index generation and other migration utilities (for example column and table rename and so on).

So you don't see index generation in your custom migration because you are using the old interface.